# How to change the attachment name?

Tags: python, html, sendmail

I am working on a function that sends emails with an attachment in PYTHON. In order to attach the file, I have to put it with the complete URL from the server, but the name of the file includes the hole URL. How can extrac only the filename from the URL.

I get the file from this URL:
/var/www/RH/HV/FILE.doc

And I want the attachment to appear
FILE.doc

here is the part of the code where i think the instructions should be added...

```
    #adjunto
    adjunto = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    adjunto.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
    encode_base64(adjunto)
    adjunto.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename= "%s"' % file)
    msg.attach(adjunto)
```

I hope someone could help!
THKS!!!

Comment: What email library are you using? If it is sendmail, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using: SMTP, email, and send mail.....I have tried the os.path.basename() but it stoped attaching the file....I'll put the code of the function to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use os.path.basename():

```
import os.path

p = '/var/www/RH/HV/FILE.doc'
print os.path.basename(p)
```

This assumes you're working with normal file paths, not URLs. But based on the question it looks like you're not looking at URLs.

Comment: THANKS....
I was adding the instruction in the wrong place.....but it worked very well